# Give value to specific rows in data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a  table like this

```
                    names                   ranges          strand
1                               [      1, 3073252]               +
2        ENSMUSG00000102693     [3073253, 3074322]               +
3                               [3074323, 3102015]               +
4        ENSMUSG00000102693     [3102016, 3102125]               +
5                               [3102126, 3252756]               + 
6        ENSMUSG00000095366     [90667525, 90667625]             -
7                               [90667626, 90754512]             -
8        ENSMUSG00000095366     [90754513, 90754821]             -
9                               [90754822, 90838868]             -
10       ENSMUSG00000096850     [90838869, 90839177]             -
```

But just some rows has "names". I want to give a value in "names" columns like below:
If "names" in 2 rows (2 and 4) are the same then the middle row (3) take that name with "new":

for example:

```
                    names                   ranges          strand
1                               [      1, 3073252]               +
2        ENSMUSG00000102693     [3073253, 3074322]               +
3        ENSMUSG00000102693_new [3074323, 3102015]               +
4        ENSMUSG00000102693     [3102016, 3102125]               +
5                               [3102126, 3252756]               + 
6        ENSMUSG00000095366     [90667525, 90667625]             -
7        ENSMUSG00000095366_new [90667626, 90754512]             -
8        ENSMUSG00000095366     [90754513, 90754821]             -
9                               [90754822, 90838868]             -
10       ENSMUSG00000096850     [90838869, 90839177]             -
```

Thanks.

Comment: Using `dput(mydata)` would be better for reproducibility

Comment: Why some rows are still blank in the expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution using `lead` and `lag`:

```
library(dplyr)
names <- c('', 'ENSMUSG00000102693', '', 'ENSMUSG00000102693', '', 'ENSMUSG00000095366', '', 'ENSMUSG00000095366', '', 'ENSMUSG00000096850')
df <- data.frame(names)
df$names <- as.character(df$names)
df$names <- ifelse((lag(df$names, default = '1') == lead(df$names, default = '2')) & (lag(df$names, default = '1') != ''), paste0(lag(df$names), '_new'), df$names)
##                    names
##1                        
##2      ENSMUSG00000102693
##3  ENSMUSG00000102693_new
##4      ENSMUSG00000102693
##5                        
##6      ENSMUSG00000095366
##7  ENSMUSG00000095366_new
##8      ENSMUSG00000095366
##9                        
##10     ENSMUSG00000096850
```

For each entry, it checks if the previous value and the next value are the same, and they are not empty strings. If the conditions are satisfied, it will copy the previous value and add `_new` to it.

Answer (score 1):

`na.locf` is a possibility here:

```
x <- c("a", NA, "a", NA, "b")
library(zoo)

fun <- function(x) {
  y <- na.locf(x) #last observation carried forward
  z <- na.locf(x, fromLast = TRUE) #last observation carried backward
  x[y == z] <- y[y == z]
  x
}

x1 <- fun(x)
#[1] "a" "a" "a" NA  "b"
x1[is.na(x) & !is.na(x1)] <- paste0(x1[is.na(x) & !is.na(x1)], "_new")
#[1] "a"     "a_new" "a"     NA      "b"
```